# Datagrid cell focus xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

How to disable next cell focusing after adding new item in datagrid? Please note that I am doing my application in MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t disable the selection of the next item. It is the intended behavior of the datagrid. 
I hope you want a behavior like when user clicks on some row it should be selected and when a new value is added you don’t want the selection to change automatically.
For that  the best thing to do is to bind the **SelectedInex** of the datagrid to some property and then set it manually when the selection changes when a data is updated.
You could also set the required behavior in the setter of **SelectedIndex** property too.

Actually there are a few way to select items in the DataGrid. It just depends which one works best for the situation

**First and most basic is SelectedIndex this will just select the Row at that index in the DataGrid**

```
 <DataGrid SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" />

private int _selectedIndex;
public int SelectedIndex
{
    get { return _selectedIndex; }
    set { _selectedIndex = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex"); }
}

SelectedIndex = 2;
```

**SelectedItem will select the row that matches the row you set**

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}" />

private DataRow _selectedRow;
public DataRow SelectedRow
{
    get { return _selectedRow; }
    set { _selectedRow = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedRow");}
}

SelectedRow = items.First(x => x.whatever == something);
```